Can the JUnit assertAll method be used to target the inside of for loop? My test is failing at the first assertion falled, not at the all of all
I have a function that queries INSEE's Base Permanente des Equipements (BPE) in search of campings in France regions.
It iterates through french regions, in this order:
Auvergne-Rhône-Alpes, Bourgogne-Franche-Comté, Bretagne, Centre-Val de Loire, Corse,
Guadeloupe, Grand Est, Guyane, Hauts-de-France, Île-de-France,
La Réunion, Martinique, Mayotte, Normandie, Nouvelle-Aquitaine,
Occitanie, Pays de la Loire, Provence-Alpes-Côte d'Azur

What I'm about to discover in this test, is that campings in overseas regions haven't been gathered by INSEE institute.
@Test
void campingsParRegion()  {
   OptionsCreationLecture options = this.equipementDataset.optionsCreationLecture();

   Dataset<Row> equipementsUnitaires = this.equipementDataset.rowEquipements(options, new HistoriqueExecution(), ANNEE_EQUIPEMENTS, false, new EquipementTriDepartementCommuneType());

   final String CAMPING = "G103";
   LOGGER.info("Nombre de campings par région :");

   assertAll(() -> {
      for (CodeRegion codeRegion : CodeRegion.regionsMetropolitainesEtOutremer()) {
         Dataset<Row> campingsRegion = equipementsUnitaires
            .where((CODE_REGION.col().equalTo(functions.lit(codeRegion.getId()))
            .and(TYPE_EQUIPEMENT.col().equalTo(functions.lit(CAMPING)))));
         long nombreCampings = campingsRegion.count();

         LOGGER.info("Nombre de campings en {} : {}", codeRegion.getNom(), nombreCampings);
         campingsRegion.show(5, false);
         assertNotEquals(0L, nombreCampings, MessageFormat.format("La région {0} devrait avoir au moins un camping", codeRegion.getNom()));
      }
   });
}

But my problem is that this test stops at its first assert failing, for Guadeloupe.
It doesn't finish the for loop, in spite of assertAll call.
2024-12-19 00:21:04.881  INFO 180966 --- [           main] f.e.a.o.s.d.e.EquipementDatasetIT        : Nombre de campings en Guadeloupe : 0

+-----+------------------+-------------+----------+----------------+----------+-----------+-----------------+----------+----------+-----------+----------+-----------------+---------------------------------+--------------+-----+----------+-------+----------------+----------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+-----------------+----------+--------------+--------------+-------------------+---------------+------------------+---------------------------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------------+---------------------------+------------------------+-------+---------------------------+---------------------------+-------------------+-----------+------------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+----------------------------------------+--------------------------------+-------------------------------+-------------+------------------------------+--------+--------+---------+--------+-----------------------+--------+----------------------+--------------------------------------------+--------+---------------------------+---------------------------+------------------------------+------------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+--------+----------------+-------------+--------------------+----------------------------------+----------------------------------+---------------------+---------------+
|annee|nomOuRaisonSociale|complementNom|numeroVoie|indiceRepetition|typeDeVoie|libelleVoie|complementAdresse|nomCommune|codePostal|codeCommune|codeRegion|domaineEquipement|sousDomaineAppartenanceEquipement|typeEquipement|siret|diffusable|cantine|presenceInternat|typeRegroupementPedagogiqueIntercommunal|presenceDispositifEducationPrioritaire|classePreparatoireAuxGrandesEcolesEnLycee|appartenanceSecteurPublicOuPriveEnseignement|accesAirePratique|accesLibre|accesSanitaire|accesVestiaire|categorieAccueilERP|presenceDouches|presenceSanitaires|presenceEquipementOuvertureExclusivementSaisonniere|partieEquipementCouverte|equipementAvecPartieEclairee|categorieEquipementCulturel|presenceCinemaMultiplexe|accueil|presenceStructureItinerante|modeDeGestionInfrastructure|sousTypeHebergement|typeDeLieux|capaciteEquipement|concernementValeursCapacite|nombreEquipementsIdentiques|concernementValeursNombreInfrastructures|nombreDeSallesParCinemaOuTheatre|concernementValeursNombreSalles|nombreDeLieux|concernementValeursNombreLieux|lambertX|lambertY|LONGITUDE|LATITUDE|qualitePositionnementXY|codeEPSG|qualiteGeolocalisation|erreurMaximumPositionnementDansVoieOuLieuDit|codeIRIS|qualiteGeoreferencementIris|indicatriceIrisationCommune|qpvAappartenanceEquipement2015|qualiteGeoreferencementQpv2015|qpvAappartenanceEquipement|qualiteGeoreferencementQpv|quartierVeilleActiveAppartenanceEquipement|qualiteGeoreferencementQuartierVeilleActive|zoneUrbaineSensibleAppartenanceEquipement|qualiteGeoreferencementZoneUrbaineSensible|codeEPCI|codeUniteUrbaine|codeBassinVie|zonageAireAttraction|codeGrilleCommunaleDensite3Niveaux|codeGrilleCommunaleDensite7Niveaux|libelleTypeEquipement|codeDepartement|
+-----+------------------+-------------+----------+----------------+----------+-----------+-----------------+----------+----------+-----------+----------+-----------------+---------------------------------+--------------+-----+----------+-------+----------------+----------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+-----------------+----------+--------------+--------------+-------------------+---------------+------------------+---------------------------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------------+---------------------------+------------------------+-------+---------------------------+---------------------------+-------------------+-----------+------------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+----------------------------------------+--------------------------------+-------------------------------+-------------+------------------------------+--------+--------+---------+--------+-----------------------+--------+----------------------+--------------------------------------------+--------+---------------------------+---------------------------+------------------------------+------------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+--------+----------------+-------------+--------------------+----------------------------------+----------------------------------+---------------------+---------------+
+-----+------------------+-------------+----------+----------------+----------+-----------+-----------------+----------+----------+-----------+----------+-----------------+---------------------------------+--------------+-----+----------+-------+----------------+----------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+-----------------+----------+--------------+--------------+-------------------+---------------+------------------+---------------------------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------------+---------------------------+------------------------+-------+---------------------------+---------------------------+-------------------+-----------+------------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+----------------------------------------+--------------------------------+-------------------------------+-------------+------------------------------+--------+--------+---------+--------+-----------------------+--------+----------------------+--------------------------------------------+--------+---------------------------+---------------------------+------------------------------+------------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+--------+----------------+-------------+--------------------+----------------------------------+----------------------------------+---------------------+---------------+

2024-12-19 00:21:05.048  INFO 180966 --- [           main] o.s.t.c.transaction.TransactionContext   : Rolled back transaction for test: [DefaultTestContext@12ff3df testClass = EquipementDatasetIT, testInstance = fr.ecoemploi.adapters.outbound.spark.dataset.equipement.EquipementDatasetIT@12b962b1, testMethod = campingsParRegion@EquipementDatasetIT, testException = org.opentest4j.MultipleFailuresError: Multiple Failures (1 failure)
    org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: La région Guadeloupe devrait avoir au moins un camping ==> expected: not equal but was: <0>, mergedContextConfiguration = [WebMergedContextConfiguration@15844237 testClass = EquipementDatasetIT, locations = '{}', classes = '{class fr.ecoemploi.adapters.outbound.spark.dataset.equipement.SparkEquipementTestApplication}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{test}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true}', contextCustomizers = set[org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@26ceffa8, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@60129b9a, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@73cd37c0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.metrics.MetricsExportContextCustomizerFactory$DisableMetricExportContextCustomizer@1800a575, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@332796d3, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestArgs@1, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestWebEnvironment@20f5239f], resourceBasePath = 'src/main/webapp', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader', parent = [null]], attributes = map['org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.activateListener' -> true, 'org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.populatedRequestContextHolder' -> true, 'org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.resetRequestContextHolder' -> true, 'org.springframework.test.context.event.ApplicationEventsTestExecutionListener.recordApplicationEvents' -> false]]

org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: La région Guadeloupe devrait avoir au moins un camping ==> expected: not equal but was: <0>

    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionUtils.fail(AssertionUtils.java:39)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertNotEquals.failEqual(AssertNotEquals.java:276)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertNotEquals.assertNotEquals(AssertNotEquals.java:121)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertNotEquals(Assertions.java:2159)
    at fr.ecoemploi.adapters.outbound.spark.dataset.equipement.EquipementDatasetIT.lambda$campingsParRegion$1(EquipementDatasetIT.java:181)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertAll.lambda$assertAll$0(AssertAll.java:68)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:992)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:921)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:682)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertAll.assertAll(AssertAll.java:77)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertAll.assertAll(AssertAll.java:44)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertAll.assertAll(AssertAll.java:38)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertAll(Assertions.java:2911)
    at fr.ecoemploi.adapters.outbound.spark.dataset.equipement.EquipementDatasetIT.campingsParRegion(EquipementDatasetIT.java:174)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:569)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:725)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:214)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:135)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:232)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:55)


org.opentest4j.MultipleFailuresError: Multiple Failures (1 failure)
    org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: La région Guadeloupe devrait avoir au moins un camping ==> expected: not equal but was: <0>

    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertAll.assertAll(AssertAll.java:80)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertAll.assertAll(AssertAll.java:44)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertAll.assertAll(AssertAll.java:38)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertAll(Assertions.java:2911)
    at fr.ecoemploi.adapters.outbound.spark.dataset.equipement.EquipementDatasetIT.campingsParRegion(EquipementDatasetIT.java:174)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:569)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:725)
[...]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:682)
        at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertAll.assertAll(AssertAll.java:77)
        ... 73 more

And if I try to surround my assert by a try...catch, which is clumsy:
try {
    assertNotEquals(0L, nombreCampings, MessageFormat.format("La région {0} devrait avoir au moins un camping", codeRegion.getNom()));

}
catch (org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError  e) {
   // Delayed
}

I am duly punished by a green test passing, in spite of regions not having campings.
How should I wrote my assertAll statement to target all the assertions done in my for loop, a manner it will display its failures only after all the loops are finished?

This is what JUnit is supposed to do.  A test fails as soon as ONE of its assertions fails.  It looks like you're trying to have separate results reported, for 20 or so different assertions.  I think what you want is probably a ParameterizedTest.  There is good documentation for those on Baeldung and in the JUnit 5 User Guide

@SitherTsering Yes, it's the same. Sorry.
